# jQuery: Add sub-object to a "data" object on every ajax request on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to extend jQuery.ajax method so it will add some static sub-data object to jQuery.ajax.data on any/every ajax request?

For example, if one of my ajax requests is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'request_file.php',
    data: {
        data1: $("#dataField1").val(),
        data2: $("#dataField2").val(),
        data3: $("#dataField3").val()
    },
    // ...
    success: function (result)
    {
        // ...
    },
    // ...
});
```

I also want "data4: window.someGlobalVar" to be automatically added in this and in any other ajax requests on the page without implicitly writing it inside every data object?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/). Do this once:

```
$.ajaxSetup({data: { "data4": window.someGlobalVar }});
```

Then, any subsequent `$.ajax` call, like the one you wrote, will include this data value.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jQuery's ajaxPrefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxprefilter/)

It is a filter that will be executed right before executing **every** ajax. There you get the options passed to the `$.ajax` method, and you could `extend` the new property, like this:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
    originalOptions.data.data4 = $("#dataField4").val()
});
```

Comment: +1 for suggestion, but @nvioli 's method is shorter and programmed exactly for that purpose. Thanks anyway.